# Python Opencv Ubuntu not creating Windows

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, opencv

I have a strange problem with opencv running on an Ubuntu.
I installed OpenCV from the apt sources. And most of the Examples work fine.

But in my programs, which are working with Mac OS, no windows are created.

The following code is showing a window and an image in this on my Mac but not on my Ubuntu powered machine

```
import time
from opencv import highgui

if __name__ == '__main__':

    highgui.cvNamedWindow('Image', highgui.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    highgui.cvMoveWindow('Image', 10, 40)
    image = highgui.cvLoadImage("verena.jpg", 1)
    highgui.cvShowImage('Image', image)
    time.sleep(3)
```

The code is taken from one of the examples that is actually working on both machines.

Comment: The two machines have different python versions but because the examples are running i don't hink that this is a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works if I add a highgui.cvStartWindowThread() call before creating the window.

Now the next question would be why the program works on mac os without starting the windowThread.

Answer (score 0):

For the new binding, I mean `cv2`. The code is `cv2.startWindowThread()`